# VSTO: changes end after exit from method that called them

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am writing a microsoft excel addin. Here is the problematic code:

```
public void XXXButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    ThisAddIn.CurrentControllerState.Name = "Calculate";             
}
```

Then, when the CurrentControllerState's name is changed an event handler is fired which passes in the new name as one of its event arguments, the event handler is:

```
public static void ChangeControllerState(object sender, ControllerStateNameChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    switch (e.NewName) 
    {                
        case "XXX":
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross;
            break;
        case...
    }            
}
```

The problem is that when the event handler XXXButton_Click ends execution, the cursor goes back to being the default cursor. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Excel Applications System Cursor:

```
this.Application.System.Cursor =
```

MSDN Ref: [Set wait cursor for Word](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9c3cc189-ee0a-43e6-b155-ecd79b4303ed/set-wait-cursor-for-word-document?forum=vsto)